# WSS having two OWSTIMER.EXE (v11 and v12) running at the same time

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I've just found that my WSS 3.0 server had two **OWSTIMER.EXE** services running:

- **SharePoint Timer Service**
  **v11**
  "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\60\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE"
- **Windows SharePoint Services Timer**
  **v12**
  "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE"

Since I'm running WSS v3, I was expecting to have only one SharePoint Timer instance, and that should be the one in th **"12"** folder.
Should I just stop the other service and keep only the **"Windows SharePoint Services Timer"** (v12) running?

Comment: Are your running Project Server at all, as this uses OWSTimer as well.

Comment: @Sam: I'm not running Project Server, just WSS with Reporting Services.

Comment: @Nelson: was this an in-place upgrade from WSS2 to WSS3?

Comment: @MattB: I can't remember that. Since this is a Win2k3 OS, it's possible that it had a WSS2 already installed out of the box, and we upgraded it to WSS3.

Comment: @Nelson: then this is a guess, but I'm going to say that it was an upgrade, and the one in the 60 hive is a remnant from WSS2. Since this isn't a common thing - I would probably stop that one during off hours and see if anything complains.

Comment: @Nelson Reis: awesome, glad I could help. Just keep an eye on the status of your timer jobs for a while to make sure everything is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but I'm going to say that this was an in-place upgrade from WSS2 to WSS3, and the one in the 60 hive is a remnant from WSS2. Since this isn't a common thing - I would probably stop that one during off hours and see if anything complains.

Comment: Right now, it all seems to work out OK, but I will continue to monitor the status of the timer.
Thanks, I couldn't find any other suggestion about this issue.